# The cone is homeomorphic to the plane

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the cone $$\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2=z^2, z\ge 0\}$$is homeomorphic to the plane

I know that an homeomorphism is a bijective fuction whose inverse is also continue. But I cannot imagine a correspondence between them.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try projecting down into the $(x, y)$ plane.

Comment: How can I do that? You can give me a hint

Comment: I already gave you a pretty strong hint. Take the projection and prove it is what you want.

Comment: Maybe $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,x^2+y^2)$? @user296602 What is confusing me is that a projection (in a vector space) is not injective, so speaking of the inverse of a projection seems strange (even if I understand what transformation you are talking about).

Comment: Well in a vector space, you have an entire line of z values. How many z values per (x, y) pair do you have here? Your inverse is close but not exactly right

Comment: @JasonCarr Thank you for your answer. What is confusing me is that if you are just given $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y,0)$, you can't find the inverse. However, if the domain $(x,y,z)\in\text{cone}$ is specified, then it is. The inverse is then $(x,y,0)\mapsto (x,y,x^2+y^2)$. Do you agree?

Comment: You need $z$ to be $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ here. And yep, it entirely depends what the domain is. Note that the function you gave is a *right* inverse even in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It just needs a restrictive enough domain to be a full inverse.

Comment: So, the homeomorphism would be $$ (x,y,0)↦(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})?$$ I understand that you did a projection but how do you know that it works.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432366/homeomorphism-in-a-cone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to remind you a definition and a theorem of interest:

> Definition: if $f : X \to Y$ is any function and $Y \subset X$ is any subset, the restriction of $f$ to $Y$ is $$f|_{y}: Y \to Z \\ f|_{y}(x)=f(x)$$

Building up on this Definition we end up with:

> Theorem 1: if $X,Z$ are topological spaces and $Y \subset Z$ has a subspace topology and if $f : X \to Z $ is continuous then $f|_{y} : Y \to Z$ is also continuous

If you want to prove this let me give a sketch. for Theorem 1 consider the map $$ i: Y \to X \\ x \to x$$ where $Y \subset X$. Then consider $f \circ i$ ($f$ composition $i$).

Now let us denote the cone by $C$.

Consider the map $$F : R^3 \to R^2 \\ (u,v,z) \to (u+v,u+v-z)$$

Now $F$ is continuous since it's coordinates are. $F$ is also a bijection. $F^{-1}$ exists. $F^{-1}$ is also continuous. Now restrict $F$ to the cone:

$$ G := F|_{C} : C \to R^2 $$

$G$ is continuous follows from the theorem. Now restrict $F^{-1}$ on $C$

$$H := F^{-1}|_C : R^2 \to C$$

By theorem $H$ is continuous. So Indeed $C$ and $R^2$ are homeomorphic to each other.