# Homeomorphism in a cone

Tags: general-topology

I have the cone  $$\{ (x,y,z) : x^2 + y^2 = z^2,z≥0 \}$$ and a plane.

Is $$f:(x,y)↦(x,y, \sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$ an homeomorphism?

Should I prove that is it injective and surjective anymore?

Comment: Probably $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? Yes, injective, surjective, continuous and also the inverse is continuous.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "surjective"? You don't need to do all that work if you can find $g$ so that $g(f(x,y))=(x,y)$ and $f(g(x,y,z))=(x,y,z)$. Here, the $g$ is easy. (After you fix your $f$.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews for example?

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430969/the-cone-is-homeomorphic-to-the-plane).